# Dell M5030 Compatability with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, updates, dell, 14.04

I'm looking to do a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell M5030 laptop running ubuntu 10.04. Will 14.04 be compatible with all the hardware (wifi drivers/usb drivers/mouse drivers/etc)? I'd have no way to revert back to 10.04 if I made the switch and then I'd have a useless laptop.

Thanks much,
 Wes

Answer (score 0):

You can first try running Ubuntu 14.04 from a flash drive or a disc and check how your hardware works out. If you're comfortable, you can go right ahead and install it.

To revert to 10.04, you can get the ISO images from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.3/